# Linq to seperate value from same table and bind to gridview

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have following table:

```
      ID    |  Type |   Desc    | Amount
  ---------------------------------------
  Stationery|  Pen  |  Red Pen  |  1.00
  Stationery|  Pen  |  Blue Pen |  1.10
  Stationery| Ruler |  A Ruler  |  1.50
  Stationery| Ruler |  B Ruler  |  1.40
```

I want get the Sum Amount for different type. The sum for Pen is 2.10, and for ruler is 2.90. How to I achieve this? I have try using "Group By". Here is my query:

```
From c In DB.Shop 
Group By c.Type 
Into TotalAmount=Sum(c.Amount) Select Type,TotalAmount
```

Then I will select the value and bind to gridview. Binding data to gridview is not the issue for me. The expected result for gridview as follow:

```
     ID    |  PenAmount | RulerAmount
-------------------------------------
 Stationery|    2.10    |   2.90
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
var query =
    (from c in DB.Shop
    group c by c.Type
    into grp
    select new
    {
        type = grp.Key,
        value = grp.Sum(g => g.Amount)
    });
```

`grp.Key` will contains `c.Type` because the grouping constructed by Type property. You may need to make some adjustment to get the exact working code, because I didn't test the linq above and I don't know exactly about your object model.

Comment: how it didn't work exactly? any error or returning different result from the expected?

Comment: @HowardHee ok, my linq is in C# syntax. And your linq should work fine in VB, that will return the expected result. So what is the problem actually?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I used following code:                        "Dim data2 = From c In DB.Shop Group c By c.Type Into grp Select New With {type=Type,value=grp.Sum(Amount)}" , blue line under "type" and "value". Error message is "Anonymous type member name must be preceded by a period."

Comment: My own linq is working fine in database view. But I want bind to gridview as expected result. I have edit my expected table.

Comment: @HowardHee about that error, it should be `{.type=Type, .value=grp.Sum(Amount)}` in VB

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var query =
    (from c in DB.Shop
    group c by c.Type
    into grp
    select new
    {
        Type= g.Key,
        PenAmount = g.Where(c => c.Type=="Pen").Sum(c => c.Amount),
        RulerAmount= g.Where(c => c.Type=="Ruler").Sum(c => c.Amount),

    });
```